# How to generate select options with values from an array?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to generate a select form using javascript, I want the form to have 9 options with the text/value from the "parties" array. However, when I run this code it only generates 1 option with all of the values from "parties" on a single line after one another. Why doesn't the loop generate 9 options as it's intended to and with only one value from the "parties" array after each option? 
Help is appreciated as I've struggled to find out the cause of this problem.

```
var parties = ["Mod", "S", "MP", "FP", "C", "SD", "KD", "F!", "V"];


var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute('method', "post");
form.setAttribute('action', "submit.php");

var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute('type', "text");
input.setAttribute('name', "username");

var submit = document.createElement("input");
submit.setAttribute('type', "submit");
submit.setAttribute('value', "Submit");

var select = document.createElement("select");

var option = document.createElement("option");

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(form);
form.appendChild(select);

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    var optionValue = parties[i];
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(optionValue);

    select.appendChild(option);
    option.appendChild(textNode);
    form.appendChild(submit);
}
```

Comment: You only create one option, but add multiple textnodes to it.

Comment: Surprised and quite pleased I haven't seen any jQuery answers :)

Comment: And the Swedish party "Moderaterna" should be shortened to "M",not "MOD" ;)

Comment: Ye I know, I think I wanted to write each party with 3 letters but changed my mind after first and didn't bother to change it haha.

Comment: Using three letters would be very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the value & text the same:

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   var option = document.createElement('option');
   option.value = option.innerHTML = parties[i];
   select.appendChild(option);
}

form.appendChild(submit);
```

Comment: It's a lot more convenient to create options in one step using the [*Option constructor*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-option): `var option = new Option(text, value)`. Also, [*option*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) content is not markup, so it doesn't have an *innerHTML* property and its content should not be set using *innerHTML* (though some browsers might allow that). Instead assign to the *text* property: `option.text = parties[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

Moved some things around.  Pay particular attention to the loop.

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwqak2q3/3/)

```
var parties = ["Mod", "S", "MP", "FP", "C", "SD", "KD", "F!", "V"];

// Create Form
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute('method', "post");
form.setAttribute('action', "submit.php");

// Create Username Input
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute('type', "text");
input.setAttribute('name', "username");
form.appendChild(input);

// Create Party Select
var select = document.createElement("select");
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(form);
form.appendChild(select);

// Add Options to Select
for (var i = 0, n = parties.length; i < n; i++) {
    var option = new Option(parties[i], parties[i]);
    select.appendChild(option);
}

// Create Submit Button
var submit = document.createElement("input");
submit.setAttribute('type', "submit");
submit.setAttribute('value', "Submit");
form.appendChild(submit);
```

---

### A closer look

```
// Add Options to Select
for (var i = 0, n = parties.length; i < n; i++) {
    var option = new Option(parties[i], parties[i]);
    select.appendChild(option);
}
```

Notice the use of caching `parties.length` into variable `n` and using that to iterate.  That way if `parties` changes in the future, you can add/remove at will.  This is only applicable if you are not purposefully restricting the number of choices to 9.

Inside the loop we use `new Option()` as user:[some](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36866) suggested, which takes two arguments; the first is the option text displayed, the second is the value of the option.

Finally, you should notice that we append the `select` to the form independent of the option creation.  I moved it before the loop to keep the select creation in one place, but it should be able to go before or after -- in fact, you may want to move the option appending down to the bottom so the page has an appearance of loading faster (this only matters to machines which have slow processors).

Comment: Great answer, will take a closer look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to round it out, you could use the [*Option constructor*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-option) and ES5 [*forEach*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) to do:

```
parties.forEach(function(value){
  select.appendChild(new Option(value, value));
}
```

but you may need a [*forEach* polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).